# Report that work with ireport but no with jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i'm design a report with ireport that work's fine but when i run the report with jasper with a java aplication get's this error

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;`

Anybody have and idea of what's could by wrong?? thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the version of Groovy you are running in your java application/IDE with the version being used by iReport.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it happens because of still u r using Groovy as ur report language, instead of Java. so u have to do is change reporting language to java. For this do like this

Select ur report file(.jrxml) -->In reporting inspector property dialog box set 'language'=java instead of groove.

(or)

check following link it will help u.

http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2010/11/how-to-handle-jasper-reports-compilationfailedexception/